# How to make VS Code LaTeX extension put extra files in a subdirectory?

Tags: auxiliary-files

Is it possible to make the extra latex files to go into some subdirectory (e.g. `.auxlatex/`)?

I am running LaTeX using the LaTeX extension on VS Code. The extra files really clog up the directories where I am working. I would rather not create some function which moves the extra files to and from the subdirectory. Is it possible to simply tell the extension's compiler to store the extra files in a subdirectory?

Comment: Having the auxiliary files in another directory usually causes more problems than it solved.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz there a good way to deal with the auxiliary files then?

Comment: Embrace them :) If you'd like to avoid very crowded folders, maybe one subfolder per tex project might help. This way you only have the auxiliary files of one projects in every folder. If you really, really can't stand the files, have a look at https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any this avoids most of the pitfalls of a separate directory for auxiliary files by moving the actual compilation somewhere else and then copy back the results.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I was afraid that was my only option ;) I'll try to get more used to them.